# XSLT template for removing an element if it does not contain a specific sub-element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am almost a complete newbie to XML and I need some help creating an XSLT template to not display a element if it does not have a populated element:

I will try to describe what I mean underneath with some example input and a desired output:

**Input:**

```
<shop>
    <item>
        <ID>12344</ID>
        <CDKNAMEDK>Dansk CD NAVN</CDKNAMEDK>
        <CDKNAMEDK>English CD name</CDKNAMEDK>
        <info>
            <Attributes>
                <authcode>DS2978</authcode>
                <PRICE>
                    <CURRENCY>DKK</CURRENCY>
                    <SALESPRICE>296</SALESPRICE>
                </PRICE>
                <Condition>used</Condition>
                <garanty>Yes</garanty>
                <garanty_length>2 months</garanty_length>
                <Label_name>demo</Label_name>
            </Attributes>
        </info>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <CDKNAMEDK>Dansk CD NAVN</CDKNAMEDK>
        <CDKNAMEDK>English CD name</CDKNAMEDK>
    </item>
</shop>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<shop>  
    <item>
        <ID>12344</ID>
        <CDKNAMEDK>Dansk CD NAVN</CDKNAMEDK>
        <CDKNAMEDK>English CD name</CDKNAMEDK>
        <info>
            <Attributes>
                <authcode>DS29783</authcode>
                <PRICE>
                    <CURRENCY>DKK</CURRENCY>
                    <SALESPRICE>296</SALESPRICE>
                </PRICE>
                <Condition>used</Condition>
                <garanty>Yes</garanty>
                <garanty_length>2 months</garanty_length>
                <Label_name>demo</Label_name>
            </Attributes>
        </info>
    </item>
</shop>
```

So, basically, if the `<info>` element is not populated, then it should hide the whole `<item>` element.

I hope someone out there is willing to give us advice on how I could achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Your Input is not well-formed XML: it is missing a single root element, and there's a mismatch between `<item>` and `</Item>` (XML is case-sensitive).  Note also that `info` in your example is an *element*, not an *attribute*.

Comment: One way to do this is to use the *identity transform* template, along with an empty template matching `item[not(info)]`.

Comment: With my edit I changed two of your elements names: `Item` to `item` and `authcodeE` to `authcode` to make the XMLs well-formed. Consider that.

Comment: Thanks zx485 and michael.hor257k, I was a little bit to fast... @michael.hor257k can you maybe give an example of the identity transform template?

Comment: See here for the identity transform: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying (or search stackoverflow for [xslt] identity transform)

Comment: Or google it - it's common enough to have an entry in Wikipedia.

Comment: Hmm, I have tried. but I'm still quite lost...

Comment: You are asking for an element which **does not contain** a specific attribute. But your XML **does not contain any attributes at all**... So how should anybody answer that question?

Comment: @alex Post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: @zx485 i mean element then....

Answer (score 2):

This simple XSLT-1.0 template should do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This template does remove the 'item' elements which do not have 'info' children -->
    <xsl:template match="item[not(info)]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT simply applies the [*identity template*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) for all nodes and ignores all `item` nodes which don't have `info` children.
The `<xsl:strip-space...` removes the empty space of the ignored elements.

Comment: Zx485. Thanks a lot! you have saved me quite some time.

Comment: @alex: Glad to read that :-) You can emphasize your appreciation by accepting this answer.